# Content Resized event for WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, events

For some scaling recalculation in a Silverlight application I use the following event:

```
 App.Current.Host.Content.Resized += new EventHandler(Content_Resized);
```

I'd like to use a similar event in a WPF application, but can not figure out what it should be.

**What is an equivalent of Silverlight's `App.Current.Host.Content.Resized` for a WPF application?**

Comment: Have you tried something like `ContentControl control = Application.Current.MainWindow.Content as ContentControl;` and then `control.SizeChanged += .....` Instead of `ContentControl` you can use whatever container you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Haris. I use just `SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged"` XAML declarated event of my app's main window. I tried your suggestion as well. They both work pretty the same. Maybe that's all I need, don't know so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF can have multiple windows which are not hosted anywhere, that is why there is no respective property in the `Application` class, if you have a conceptual main window you can set the application's [`MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) property and handle `Application.Current.MainWindow.`[`SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) instead.